# Duplicate records using inner join with Three tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working with 3 tables and I am finding difficulty in constructing a SQL query which returns unique set of records. I am using Oracle SQL.

If I include the UDG_Description fields I get duplicate records.

I have tried using 'distinct' on the Table1.MachId but I think that is incorrect way of using it for my query.

I noticed that if I include the UDG_Description I get duplicates but I need the description of the record from Table 3 in regards to the output i am trying to generate.

I appreciate if someone can assist me please?

Below is the current setup i am currently working with

**Table1**

- MachId
- MachCode
- MachLinkType

**Table2**

- LevId
- Lev_UDG_Code(linked to the Table 3)
- Lev_MachCode(linked to table1)

**Table3**

- UDG_Id
- UDG_prefix
- UDG_code
- UDG_description

**Note**
The UDG_CODE is not unique. The udg_prefix and udg_id have to be unique.

```
SELECT distinct(MachId), MachCode, MachLinkType, Lev_UDG_Code, UDG_Description 
from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.MachCode = Table2.Lev_MachCode
INNER JOIN Table2 ON
Table3.UDG_Code = Table2.Lev_UDG_Code
WHERE MachLinkType = 'ATX' AND Lev_UDG_Code = '12A89'
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always works on all columns in the select list. Btw: you do not have any PL/SQL in your question. So why did you add the `plsql` tag.

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  Better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: If `Lev_UDG_Code` and `Lev_MachCode` aren't in a unique relationship, which one should you pick?

Comment: The reason I tagged it with PL/SQL is because I am using PL/SQL developer and the tables are in an oracle database. If that caused offence that sorry but your tone isn't helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a unique list of codes/description from table3 before the join. Like such

```
SELECT MachId,
       MachCode,
       MachLinkType,
       Lev_UDG_Code,
       tbl3.UDG_Description 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MachCode = Table2.Lev_MachCode
INNER JOIN (SELECT UDG_CODE, 
                   UDG_Description 
            FROM Table3
            GROUP BY UDG_COD, 
                     UDG_Description) tbl3
ON tbl3.UDG_Code = Table2.Lev_UDG_Code
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance everyone. I will get back to you soon as I have tried the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
select distinct MachId,
                MachCode,
                MachLinkType,
                Lev_UDG_Code,
                UDG_Description 
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.MachCode = Table2.Lev_MachCode
inner join Table3 on Table3.UDG_Code = Table2.Lev_UDG_Code
where MachLinkType = 'ATX' and Lev_UDG_Code = '12A89'
```

Comment: If you want a unique set of results from all columns, use `DISTINCT` (that's what it's there for).  If you're aggregating (`MAX(..)`, whatever), use `GROUP BY`.  I have a feeling this won't solve the OP's problem anyways...